# asp.net auto generated textboxes ID on webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using **C#** on **Visual Studio**. I want to generate a **webform** with auto numbered `Textboxes` depending on the input from the previous page. What is the best way to do this loop?

For example:

Input is 4

The next page should generate textboxes with ID of

- "name1"
- "name2"
- "name3"
- "name4"

Something like this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="name1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="name2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="name3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="name4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Part 2 of my question is that if I want to call them when a `Button` is click, how should I use a loop the get those ID?

Answer (score 2):

Use for loop and `PlaceHolder` control to create dynamic `TextBox` controls

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phDynamicTextBox" runat="server" />

int inputFromPreviousPost = 4;
for(int i = 1; i <= inputFromPreviousPost; i++)
{
    TextBox t = new TextBox();
    t.ID = "name" + i.ToString();
}

//on button click retrieve controls inside placeholder control
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(Control c in phDynamicTextBox.Controls)
   {
       try
       {
           TextBox t = (TextBox)c;

           // gets textbox ID property
           Response.Write(t.ID);
       }
       catch
       {

       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create those controls in the Page `Init` event handler by say loop for the number of times the control needs to made available.

Please remember since these are dynamic controls they need to be recreated during postbacks and will not be done automatically.

Further [Dynamic controls and postback](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check this code.
In first page...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {          
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?Name=" + TextBox1.Text);
  }
```

In second page you can get the value from querystring and create controls dynamically

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (Request.QueryString["Name"] != null)
          Response.Write(Request.QueryString["Name"]);

            Int32 howmany = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["Name"]);

            for (int i = 1; i < howmany + 1; i++)
            {
                TextBox tb = new TextBox();
                tb.ID = "name" + i;
                form1.Controls.Add(tb);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( int i=0; i<4; i++ )
{
   TextBox t = new TextBox();
   t.ID = "name" + i.ToString();

   this.Controls.Add( t );
}
```

Comment: He should also use a Placeholder control to have control over where the resulting controls end up on the page.

Comment: sure, `this.Controls.Add` is just an example